# Can Javascript get third-party HTTP response code from window.open?

Tags: javascript, http

Javascript opens a third-party web page using `window.open(other_site_url,'_blank')`.

Can the script on the first web page determine the HTTP response code for the second?

Comment: You can use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) directly to get data from other sources. 
Or simply use localstorage / cookies, or some sort of intermediate mechanism to communicate between both pages.

Comment: I'm aware of XMLHttpRequest, it's intentionally excluded from the premise of the question. The third party web page has *already been opened* via `window.location`.